# How to access extension property inside object from outside class?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

Example:

```
class Foo {
    fun foo() = Unit
}

object Bar {
    val Foo.foo get() = Unit
}

fun Foo.bar() = Bar.foo
```

Extension symbols aren't static when inside a class instance, so I don't see why this wouldn't be possible by simply passing in the receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to bring the `Bar` into the context as a receiver as well, along with reference to `someFoo.foo` otherwise you are saying `Bar` has a property `foo` which it does not.  It has within its scope (and its instance) the extension of `Foo.foo`.  Therefore change your last line from:

```
fun Foo.bar() = Bar.foo
```

to:

```
fun Foo.bar() = with (Bar) { foo }
```

which is conceptually this:

```
fun Foo.bar() = with (Bar) { this@bar.foo }
```

So we use `with` to stack the `Bar` receiver under the `Foo` instance receiver of `this@bar` and access the property `foo`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh, genius. Thanks! Still reported it since that really shouldn't be necessary: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26395

Comment: It is necessary, there are two receivers in context and they MUST be provided.  This was already reported as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24290 and the same answer given there.